# ImportError: No module named 'pandas.testing'

Tags: pandas

Thank you in advance. I have pandas-datareader==0.7.0+7.g7949e60 succesfull installed, but when i run the scripts, appears this:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pepew/sss/screener/cargadordatos.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
  File "/home/pepew/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "/home/pepew/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.av.forex import AVForexReader
  File "/home/pepew/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/av/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.base import _BaseReader
  File "/home/pepew/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader._utils import (RemoteDataError, SymbolWarning,
  File "/home/pepew/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.compat import is_number
  File "/home/pepew/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/compat/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
     ImportError: No module named 'pandas.testing'
>>>
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: i'm using pandas version 0.23.4.. perhaps if i install pandas version 0.20.0?

Comment: Are you sure? `from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal` works for me in 0.23.4.

Comment: Well, this issue is in pythonanywhere.. The script is working perfectly in my Anaconda3 in my pc. I checked pc site-packages and i had pandas-0.19.2-py3.6.egg-info and pandas_datareader-0.7.0.dist-info installed. So i installed the same versions of both packages in PA and i nothing changed...No idea what is wrong..Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas-datareader appears to [require](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/requirements.txt) pandas version 0.19.2+. But the `pandas.testing` module was only added in [0.20.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#pandas-testing)

A workaround would be to upgrade the pandas package: `pip install pandas -U`

Comment: Datareader only imports ``pandas.testing`` if the pandas version is >= 0.20.0. Else it imports ``pandas.util.testing`` (see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/compat/__init__.py)). My guess is that OP has a pandas version < 0.19.2 and that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my pandas version is 0.23.4. I continue having the issue.

Comment: How can install pandaa version 0.20.0?

Comment: @pepew `pip install pandas==0.20.0`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas Datareader requires pandas version 0.19.2 or higher. This error is likely due to the fact that your pandas version is before 0.19.2. If this is the case, the best way to update pandas is:

`pip install pandas -U`